# (Possible) inconsistent behavior of grep and less

Tags: files, grep, unicode, character-encoding, less

I have a utf-8 file containing some Turkish text inside. (My system is MacOSX)

```
$ file -I foo.merge
$foo.merge: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

When I try to see some Turkish specific characters by using `grep`, there is no problem:

```
$ grep 'Emiroğlu' foo.merge
EMİROĞLU    Emiroğlu+Noun+A3sg+Pnon+Nom Emiroğlu+Noun+Prop+Noun+A3sg+P3sg+Nom   Emiroğlu+Noun+Prop+Noun+A3sg+Pnon+Nom   NOTFOUND
```

I can also see the file by using `less` command without any problem.

However if I try to do the following, the Turkish characters are not seen properly:

```
$ grep 'Emir' foo.merge | less
EMİROĞLU        ESC[1;35;40mESC[KEmirESC[mESC[Koğlu+Noun+A3sg+Pnon+Nom  ESC[1;35;40mESC[KEmirESC[mESC[Koğlu+Noun+Prop+Noun+A3sg+P3sg+Nom        ESC[1;35;40mESC[KEmirESC[mESC[Koğlu+Noun+Prop+Noun+A3sg+Pnon+Nom        NOTFOUND
```

Or the following also doesn't work:

```
$grep 'Emir' foo.merge > foo2.out
$less foo2.out
```

What could be the problem?  Here is some additional information:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.utf-8"
```

Comment: I guess (s)he meant the Turkish characters are not appeared in the second example as he seeks and this is a problem @Kusalananda

Comment: @zwlayer Oh, I saw `EMİROĞLU` and thought that was the expected output.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yup, `EMİROĞLU` is the part of the expected output. But I guess problem occurs in the second part of that output where (s)he gets  `ESC[1;35;40mESC[KEmirESC[mESC[Koğlu` instead of `Emiroğlu`

Comment: Your `grep` is using terminal control sequences to highlight (color) the matched string, which `less` does not understand by default. Look for a `grep` option to turn off coloring (in GNU `--color=never` or `--color=auto`) or use `less -R` to tell it to understand terminal coloring. If you (want to) use these a lot you may want to make them aliases or functions in your shell profile.

Answer (score 1):

The Turkish characters look fine. However grep has inserted colour codes into the output.

Choices:

- add option `--color=never` to grep (to remove colour).
- add option `-R` to less (to tell less to interpret ASCII colour codes).